# Can I use onTap property and onSave property simultaneously in a Textformfield in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am working on a project which requires a form for the sign up process. I want to change the current state of the text form field when the user taps it and show a border around the text field. And when the user clicks the submit button  his credentials entered in the respected form field should be saved.

One feasible solution which came to my mind is that for the first one I should use the `onTap` property and for the second one I should use the `onSaved` property and the `setState` method in each of them. But is this allowed in flutter?

Comment: Can you include your code snippet that you've tried so far

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to get your mentioned result. I hope this is what you need

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class ABC {}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  GlobalKey<FormState> _key = GlobalKey();
  String? username;
  String? password;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Form(
          key: _key,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "Enter Username",
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue)),
                ),
                onSaved: (val) => username = val,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "Enter Password",
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue)),
                ),
                onSaved: (val) => password = val,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    final form = _key.currentState;
                    if (form!.validate()) {
                      form.save();
                    }
                  },
                  child: Text("Submit"))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```